# Using langdetect output to be imported into a new column in my dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Being rather new to programming with python I tried to language detect segments of text in pandas data frame. 
So first I made a function for the 'langdetect' package

```
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect

def language_detect(x):
    lang = detect(x)
    print(lang)
```

My second step would be to feed in the data frame for processing. All the segments that need detecting are in separate rows in the dataframe under the same column header.

```
result = [language_detect(x) for x in df['column_name']]
```

```
df['l_detect'] = pd.append(result)
```

In the output I see the texts being recognized properly.
But when I try to print result.
it returns me with only the value for every entry 'none'

So my questions are:

1. why do I get 'none' when the the print output from the function has the right values
2. How can I attach this to my current data frame, since when I try to append it I get 'none' on 
     every field as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `result` is empty because your function `language_detect()` doesn't return anything (it is only printing the results).

```py
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect

lst = [('this is a test', 1), ('what language is this?', 4), ('stackoverflow is a website', 23)]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['text', 'something'])

def language_detect(x):
    lang = detect(x)
    print(lang)

result = [language_detect(x) for x in df['text']]
result
#Output:[None, None, None]
```

Just give it a return value:

```py
def language_detect(x):
    lang = detect(x)
    return lang

df['l_detect'] = df['text'].apply(language_detect)

df.head()
#Output:
#                         text  something l_detect
#0              this is a test          1       en
#1      what language is this?          4       en
#2  stackoverflow is a website         23       en
```

and it will work as expected.